# Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

Here is the error:

```
Dynamic SQL Error    
SQL error code = -104    
Token unknown - line 1, column 162    
VALUE
```

Here is the code:

```
using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(@"SELECT DOC_ITEMS.ID, PRODUCTS.PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTS.NAME, DOC_ITEMS.QUANTITY, UNITS.UNIT, DOC_ITEMS.PRICE, DOC_ITEMS.TAX, (DOC_ITEMS.PRICE * DOC_ITEMS.QUANTITY) AS VALUE
                        FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN
                        DOC_ITEMS ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID = DOC_ITEMS.PRODUCTID INNER JOIN
                        UNITS ON PRODUCTS.UNITID = UNITS.UNITID
                        WHERE (DOC_ITEMS.DOCUMENTID = @DocumentID)", con))

{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentID", documentId);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    dataGridView1.Columns["PRODUCTKEY"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["NAME"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView1.Columns["QUANTITY"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["QUANTITY"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    dataGridView1.Columns["UNIT"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["PRICE"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["PRICE"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00 $";
    dataGridView1.Columns["TAX"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["TAX"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0\\%";
    dataGridView1.Columns["VALUE"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["VALUE"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00 $";
}
```

When I run this command through my database directly it is working ok but inside my c# code it drops this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `""VALUE""` with double quotes since one quote will close your string.

Answer (score 1):

`VALUE` is a [reserved word](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-reskeywords-reswords) in Firebird, this means it can't be used in a query as an object name. You need to either use a different name, or explicitly quote it as `"VALUE"`, so the query parser knows it is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create a table in my Interbase database.

> Dynamic SQL Error
>   SQL error code = -104
>   Unexpected end of command

and this is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE Medecin(
    Code Integer ,
    Nom varchar(30) ,
    prénom varchar(30) ,
    spécialité varchar(30) ,
    Adresse varchar(50) ,
    telephone varchar(14)
);
```

What is wrong here?